# Lotus Notes: Controlling input on multi-value fields

Tags: lotus-notes

I have been using multi-value checkbox field. Now I want to disable some of the checkboxes depending on criteria. For example if field A has value "no license" then disable field B's checkbox with value "car" but leave values "bike" and "train" available for user to select.

Having all the values in the same field would make handling the checked values easier but is it possible to modify multi-value field to work like that?

Answer (score 3):

You need to compute the values allowed in the multi-value check box field based on the value of FieldA.

```
@If(FieldA = "No License"; "Bike":"Train"; "Car":"Bike":"Train")
```

You then need to set properties on the Checkbox field like this:

[image: Notes Form field Properties second tab]

And on FieldA like this:

[image]

This will refresh the field choices for the checkbox whenever the value in FieldA changes

Comment: Upvoted your solution because of screenshots

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to selectively disable single values from checkbox. You can just remove the option completely so that it cannot be selected anymore.

So instead of just typing the values for the checkbox, use a formula to calculate them like:

```
@If( fieldA = "no license" ; 
     "bike" : "train" ; 
     "car" : "bike" : "train" )
```

The formula could be as complex / simple as you want. e.g. something like:

```
_licenseNeeded := "car" : "taxi" : "motorbike";
_other := "bike" : "train";

@Trim( @If( fieldA = "no license" ; ""; _licenseNeeded ) : _other )
```